# DWA-131 driver fail using beaglebone as wi-fi hostspot

Tags: beagleboneblack, hostapd

I'm trying to create a wi-fi hostspot using a beaglebone black rev-C and DWA-131 nano wi-if adapter.

I followed this article to install the driver:
http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2013-11-16-d-link-dwa-131-n300-usb-wifi-adapter

And this project do setup the hostapd: https://github.com/jekader/hostapd-rtl

But when I try to start I'm getting the following error:

```
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
drv->ifindex=4
l2_packet_init: ioctl[SIOCGIFINDEX]: No such device
no br0 interface , let l2_sock_recv==l2_sock_xmit=0x0x51648
ioctl[SIOCSIWMODE]: Operation not supported
Could not set interface to mode(3)!
Could not set interface to master mode!
rtl871xdrv driver initialization failed.
rmdir[ctrl_interface]: No such file or directory
```

My hostapd.conf is:

```
interface=usb0
driver=rtl871xdrv
bridge=br0
ssid=NETWORK-NAME
channel=1
wmm_enabled=0
wpa=1
wpa_passphrase=NETWORK-PASSWORD
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
auth_algs=1
macaddr_acl=0
```

Hostapt version? Driver's name or config?

ps: I'm not confortable because my network interface for the wi-fi is usb0 instead of wlan0. Is a driver issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had same compilation issues. Following is working very well, you get the source directly from git.

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make
sudo make install
```